# Как правильно закинуть в проект файл persistance.xml?

Tags: java

Имею проект maven quickstart, в нем нету ни папки meta-inf, ни properties.
Как добавить к нему файл `persistance.xml`?

Comment: Какой этап первый?

Comment: Так как закинуть?

Comment: Я бы не стал вообще с этим возиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте архетип `maven` проекта `webapp`.

Можете использовать эту команду для создания:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=1.4
```

Архетип `quickstart` по умолчанию, не предусматривает структуру проекта в которой будут папки `META-INF` и прочие для построения веб приложения.

Так же вы можете ознакомиться с похожей проблемой в уже существующем [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871109/where-to-put-persistence-xml-in-library-jar-using-maven).